# Screwed up on clone job

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone

Okay here is the short version of a long story... So I got a new SSD and I cloned my HDD to it, and didn't realize it but I managed to some how to make the system reserve partition over 9gbs big by accident (as the picture indicates), So my question is, is there anyway to shrink that down and regain that space without going through the whole cloning process again?

Any ideas would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Simplest solution would to simply use the software used to clone your HDD again.  But you should be able to shrink the partition.

Comment: Can you just right-click on the partition and shrink it? If not, you'll need to use a more sophisticated partition resizing tool.

Answer (score 1):

get partedmagic or similiar burn it to a CD and boot from it.

Launch partition editor

select the correct hard drive

Right click resize.

shrink as necessary

expand another partition into the unused space

click apply

wait

close

reboot

done